# Symfon2: How to set default values (options) for Entity field type?

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I am creating a form which uses an Entity type. 
The entity form type displays Roles as a list of checkboxes.
But I dont know how to set default values. I need to get default values from DB then dynamically check some of those options.

According to the documentation, It seems like 'preferred_choices' option won't do this job.

Can anyone please help me out there?

Sorry about my English if some sentences don't make sense.

3 Tables:

UserRole

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| role_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

AdminUser

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username  | varchar(25) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| salt      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password  | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email     | varchar(60) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| is_active | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Role

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Form builder:

```
$builder->add('role', 'entity', array(

    'class' => 'AcmeAdminBundle:Role',

    'property' => 'name',

    'multiple' => TRUE,

    'expanded' => TRUE,

));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have defined a ManyToMany relation between User and Role, with some traditional methods on User entity : setRoles, getRoles, addRole...

**Data that will be loaded in your form are data from a User instance**, for example $user.

```
$user = new User; // or $user is existing User, same logic
$rolesYouWantToSetToUser = array('ROLE_1', 'ROLE_2', 'ROLE_3');

foreach ($rolesYouWantToSetToUser as $roleId) {
    // $em must previsouly be set as EntityManager in your code
    $role = $em->getReference('YourBundle:Role', $roleId);
    $user->addRole($role);
}

// From a controller
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AcmeAdminBundle:Role',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'property' => 'name',
            ))
            ->getForm();
```